# Loading extensions in sqliteman

Tags: sqlite

I'm trying to dynamically load an extension in [sqliteman](http://sqliteman.yarpen.cz/). I have no issues loading it directly through `sqlite3`:

```
sqlite> select load_extension('path/extension.so');
```

But when I do the same in `sqliteman` I get the error

```
Query Error: not authorized Unable to fetch row
```

In both cases, `ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION` is compiled in.

```
sqlite> select sqlite_compileoption_used('ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION');
1
```

What am I missing in `sqliteman`? Why can't I load extensions through that interface?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that despite the above being true, the [version of `sqliteman` installable on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/sqliteman) (1.2.2) doesn't have the ability to load extensions. The current development version (1.3) does, however, and is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/pvanek/sqliteman).

I was able to install this on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (xenial) as follows:

```
$ sudo apt install qt4-qmake qt4-dev-tools       # dependencies
$ git clone https://github.com/pvanek/sqliteman  # worked as of commit 090e390
$ cd sqliteman/Sqliteman
$ cmake -DWANT_INTERNAL_QSCINTILLA=1 .           # used internal QScintilla library
$ make
$ make install                          # note: requires write access to /usr/local
```

Running the version thus installed at `/usr/local/bin/sqliteman` allowed loading extensions as expected and described above.